Не получается в Фронтенд вывести значение которое принял из бд в Бэкенде
Бэкенд
    connection.execute("SELECT `Dragons` FROM users", function(err, results){
        console.log(err)
        console.log(results)
        const ggs = results
        app.get('/back', (req, res) => {
            res.json({
                ggs
            })
        })
     })

Данные получаются из БД mysql и отображаются как
{"ggs":[{"Dragons":7842}]}
в консоли бэкенда.
Я так понимаю Фронт принимает но не знает как отобразить такой объект.
Фронтенд

 const [steng, setData] = useState(null)
        useEffect(() => {
            fetch('/back')
            .then(response => response)
            .then(response => setData(response.ggs))
        },[]) 
        return(
            <div className="Menu">
                <div className="Info_Bar" onClick={ClickedInfo}></div>
                <div className="Dragons">Famously dynasty:{steng}</div>


2 недели искал как  соединить бэкенд и фронтенд, думал во нашел и то косяк. Если есть другая возможность соединить их буду рад узнавать новое :)

Вам бы javascript для начала подучить, потом браться за реакт. В целом, если клинт данные принимает и сетит их, то в переменной steng у вас лежит массив объектов. Что бы вывести первое значение, то можно сделать так в рендере dynasty:{steng[0].Dragons} или использовать метод map массивов для отрисовки списков

Возможо вы гуру профессионал, я же не говорю что хвастаюсь знаниями. Вариант предложенный вами так же не работает.

Что пишет? Есть ли ошибки? Что приходит на фронт в переменной response? Может там строка лежит и надо сделать response.json()? Что сохраняется в стейт? Понатыкайте консоль логов

Не получается вывести что принимает steng. Если кидать в {steng[0].Dragons} то во Фронте отображается ошибка  TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '0') . Если выводить просто steng, то все работает но не отображается содержимое steng.

И так я продвинулся, добавил cors, добавилJSON.stringify(results);  В итоге получаю строку в виде массива json на фронте: [{\"Dragons\":999999}]. Вопрос в чем, мне нужно показать только данные из столбца Dragons  т.е значение 999999 а не весь json массив. Искал в инете пока не нашел ответа.
Получил желаемый результат! [{\"Dragons\":999999}] из этой строки срезал  сначала и конца. Знаю что максимально убого пока что, учусь.....

Сначала идет инициализация роута, потом идет выборка данных.
app.get('/back', (req, res) => {
  connection.execute("SELECT `Dragons` FROM `users`", (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err);
      return;
    }

    res.json({
      ggs: results
    });
  });
});

На фронте обязательно проверьте статус код (должен быть 200) и сделайте десериализацию
    const [steng, setData] = useState(null)
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('/back')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => setData(response.ggs))
    }, [])
        return(
            <div className="Menu">
                <div className="Info_Bar" onClick={ClickedInfo}></div>
                <div className="Dragons">Famously dynasty:{steng}</div>


Не хочет так же, после вашего исправления заметил, при обновлении страницы во Фронте, в бэкенде console.log(results) выводится 4 раза.

При обновлении так же выдает ошибку на доли секунды и исчезает. Заснял на видео и замедлил пишет: Objects are not valid as a React child(found: objests wuth keys {Dragons}).If you mean to render a collection children, use an array instead.

Вывел принятые данные  и вывел как alert получается такое: [object Object]
